# is it possible to see an image in facebook but not being able to download it by opengraph?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I wrote some python code to download all images from my friends.

So far it is working pretty nicely, however, some of my friends returns empty data from the albums and photos that I ask opengraph to get...

Example:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ id_friend + '/photos?access_token='+AT+'&limit=9999999'
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ id_friend + '/albums?access_token='+AT+'&limit=9000'
```

where `ID_FRIEND` is exactly what the name tells you and `AT` is the access token that I need to access the photos.

For almost all friends, it works flawlessly, but some of them, it returns an empty list. When I browse to that particular user using a browser, it shows all the pictures, without any problem...

What am I doing wrong so that I can't download those photos using opengraph, but still be able to see them when browsing through chrome?